# css selector question

Tags: css, class

I have a table that looks something like this.

**EDIT - I re-extracted code. I think the question makes more sense now. (Answers may not)**

```
  <div class="view view-latest-news-view view-id-latest_news_view view-display-id-latest_news_block_1 view-dom-id-1">
     <div class="views-admin-links views-hide">
     </div>
  <div class="view-content">
  <table class="views-view-grid">
     <tr class="row-1 row-first">
        <td class="col-1">
        </td>
     </tr>   
  <table>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I address only the "views-view-grid"  tables that are contained by the "view-latest-news-view" class? Something like this...

```
.view-latest-news-view table.views-view-grid  {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

** END EDIT **

Thanks!

** ANSWER: ** 
this works... but maybe I could be more specific?

```
.view-latest-news-view .views-view-grid  {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because `<table class="views-generic-grid">` is not contained with in any element with the class `views-admin-links`.  (You open the div and then immediately close it, so it has no children.)

So when you say this:

> How can I address only the "views-generic-grid" tables that are contained by the "views-admin-links" class?

The answer is you can't, because there are no "views-generic-grid" tables contained in elements with the "views-admin-links" class.

Either extend the div to surround the table, or pick a different selector than `.views-admin-links`.

Comment: And I'm still finding things wrong... there's a missing `</div>` somewhere... I'm wondering if the markup pasted is just a trimmed-down example that got too trimmed. :/

Answer (score 0):

The way your markup is right now, you can't, you have to extend `.views-admin-links` to surround the entire `.views-generic-grid` table, and then you can write a selector like this:

```
.views-admin-links .views-generic-grid
```